# How can I animate dialog in Jetpack compose Navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, jetpack-compose-navigation

I have a question about animating dialogs.

in basic library, there's a dialog function. But it doesn't seem I can apply some animation when it opens.
So, I created this function called animatedDialog. Is this normal way or does this have any problem or is there any better solution to solve this issue?

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.animatedDialog(
    route: String,
    arguments: List<NamedNavArgument> = emptyList(),
    deepLinks: List<NavDeepLink> = emptyList(),
    enter: EnterTransition = fadeIn() + expandIn(),
    exit: ExitTransition = shrinkOut() + fadeOut(),
    dialogProperties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties(),
    content: @Composable (NavBackStackEntry) -> Unit
) {
    addDestination(
        Destination(
            provider[AnimatedDialogNavigator::class],
            enter = enter,
            exit = exit,
            dialogProperties,
            content
        ).apply {
            this.route = route
            arguments.forEach { (argumentName, argument) ->
                addArgument(argumentName, argument)
            }
            deepLinks.forEach { deepLink ->
                addDeepLink(deepLink)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: @FRINTSO So, you mean, my approach is Okay? I used `EnterTransition`, `ExitTransition`.

Comment: Is there anyway to use NavGraphBuilder.dialog() that google provides by default? @FRINTSO

Comment: What about this library? https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/navigation-animation

Comment: Dialogs are separate Android windows, they don't respect any animations you set in Compose. That is true with or without Navigation. That's why `Dialog` itself has no animation properties. What were you expecting this code to do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I wanted to give a dialog(in Navigation) animation like fade in/fade out whenever it shows and it dismisses.

I don't understand the part 'they don't respect any animations'. Does it that mean, windows can't have animation? Why do they not respect compose animations?